# Difference between UTM CRS with 6 digits and 8 digits

Tags: coordinate-system, utm, germany

In my area in Germany we use the CRS with the EPSG:25832 code. These are UTM 32N coordinates with a false easting of 500,000. Thus, it is a 6 digit coordinate system. I read this means that the middle meridian has the value 500,000m.

Sometimes I get data with the EPSG:5652 code which is also a UTM 32N System. But it has a false easting of 32,500,000. The false easting has 8 digits. I read that the 32 refers to the Zone 32.

What are the differences between both CRS?

In what situations is it recomended to use which version?

Comment: It should actually be 32,**5**00,000 and equals the usual zonal meridian value of 500,000m plus a *zone prefix*! Note that the axis order is reversed compared to EPSG:25832. [More info](https://epsg.io/5652).

Comment: Compare http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832 and http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::5652.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two coordinate systems are quite similar. The difference is on the 'False Easting'.

This means that if a point coordinates in the EPSG 25832 are **X, Y** (X for east coordinate and Y for north coordinate), the coordinates of this point in the EPSG 5652 are **X + 32,000,000, Y**.

The idea behind this is to be able to recognize coordinates based on their value. If you get coordinates without knowing their EPSG but East coordinates are near 32 000 000, you will know that those coordinates are in EPSG 5652.
And for example, if you received coordinates with East near 31 000 000, those coordinates are in EPSG 5651 (same logic but with UTM 31).

According to links provided by @user30184, there is one last difference. Axis are reversed between both system. If you get coordinates in EPSG 35832, those should be **E, N** but coordinates in EPSG 5652 should be organize as **N, E** coordinates.